# Where can I find a list of timezone options available during install process of a distro?

Tags: linux, system-installation, debian-installer, timezone, installer-anaconda

I'm building an app where it makes sense for the user to be able to select a different timezone than their actual own timezone for certain operations, without going too much into details, I can assure you it actually makes sense to support multiple timezones for certain niche operations.

I'm aware of the IANA TZ Database, but I was wondering if any distro supplies a list of the ones that are current as a list with timezone and offset information in any format and save me some trouble of parsing the DB.

The timezone database tends to contain full historic information as far as I can tell, though I'm looking for the currently valid/available information at 'now'. And it's kind of useful to just inherit the decisions from the installer if they have deemed some of these to be superfluous information/not shown to the user and I'd like to inherit these pretty much.

Since I figured the setup/installers of the distros already show/have this information available, I was wondering where I could obtain one.

Thanks :)

Comment: `tzselect` is the interactive command line tool... otherwise for a list of TZs you just run `timedatectl list-timezones` (optionally with `--no-pager` if don't want to use a pager...)

Answer (score 1):

If your users aren't all adept Linux administrators, they will probably find tzselect more intuitive than other options. It is a CLI menu-driven system that allows one to select a region, then country, then zone. The first menu looks like this:

```
root@scrspdimsolr01:~# tzselect
Please identify a location so that time zone rules can be set correctly.
Please select a continent, ocean, "coord", or "TZ".
 1) Africa
 2) Americas
 3) Antarctica
 4) Asia
 5) Atlantic Ocean
 6) Australia
 7) Europe
 8) Indian Ocean
 9) Pacific Ocean
10) coord - I want to use geographical coordinates.
11) TZ - I want to specify the timezone using the Posix TZ format.
#?
```

After a few options, it spits out a command one can use to set personal timezone variables - the output could either be parsed and used or one could followup and have the user cut and paste the response suggested into another prompt. The results after going through the menu look like this:

```
You can make this change permanent for yourself by appending the line
        TZ='America/Los_Angeles'; export TZ
to the file '.profile' in your home directory; then log out and log in again.

Here is that TZ value again, this time on standard output so that you
can use the /usr/bin/tzselect command in shell scripts:
America/Los_Angeles
```

As the last line is going to STDOUT, you can set it and/or pipe it to a users's .profile (.profile is for seperate Linux logins, or you can set the timezone live for that user in that instance).

Answer (score 0):

I guess all distribution ship the IANA TZ Database, for both Fedora and Debian the package is called `tzdata` and you'll find the database in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. But the easiest way should be to use some library that provides these information already parsed. This depends on the language or framework you are using. For example if you are using Python you can use the `datetime` and `zoneinfo` ([zoneifnfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) was added in 3.9, you can also use [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) which has similar API but isn't part of the python standard library)  modules:

```py
import datetime
import zoneinfo

zoneinfo.available_timezones()  # simple list of all timezones

zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('US/Alaska').utcoffset(datetime.datetime.now())  # utc offset in datetime format
```

And this is actually exactly what Anaconda, the Fedora installer, [does](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/blob/master/pyanaconda/timezone.py) because it is written in Python.

Comment: Isn't that feature actually pretty new in Python? I think it was added in the last couple of years or so, before that you'd need to install a separate package.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize that, I added information about the pytz module which could be used with older versions of Python 3.